# Does usort preserve an existing order

Tags: php

If I have a list of objects sorted by date and then use `usort()` to sort them by another property will they remain sorted by date when appropriate? If not how can I make sure of that?

```
usort( $result, function( $a, $b ) {
    if( $a['distance'] < $b['distance'] ) {
        return -1;
    } elseif( $a['distance'] > $b['distance'] ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

`$result` is sorted by date, though the property expressing that date is no longer attached. `$a['distance']` is a float.

Final implementation :

```
usort( $result, function( $a, $b ) {
    if( $a['distance'] < $b['distance'] ) {
        return -1;
    } elseif( $a['distance'] > $b['distance'] ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if( $a['date'] < $b['date'] ) {
            return -1;
        } elseif( $a['date'] > $b['date'] ) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

`$a['date']` is a DateTime object

Comment: show us example with code

Comment: @NullPoiиteя added the code though I'm not sure that it will help as it is a very straight forward use of usort.

Comment: Post your array structure along with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think that keeping previous order is defined (guaranteed). But you should handle it in your comparing function. So, just compare two items by date and then by that other property if dates are the same (or other way, not sure what you want) so you'll get your array ordered by 2 criterias.

```
usort( $result, function( $a, $b ) {
    if( $a['distance'] < $b['distance'] ) {
        return -1;
    } elseif( $a['distance'] > $b['distance'] ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
       // Here don't return 0 but do other comparation by other criteria.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added my final implementation based on your answer to the question.